# How to filter model results for multiple values dynamically in django

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I have following course model with professor, code, semester_season, semester_year, etc

I have request post values:

```
coursecode = request.POST['coursecode']
courselist = request.POST['courselist']
semesteryear = request.POST['semesteryear']
semesterseason = request.POST['semesterseason']
```

this is my filter a queryset for finding above post values:

```
course_listobj = Course.objects.filter(
  code=coursecode,
  title=courselist,
  semester_year=semesteryear,
  semester_season=semesterseasonid).order_by(
    'code', 'title', 'semester_year', 'semester_season')
```

This is my front end:
[image]

how can find if one post value is empty find other values in query set dynamically i mean

if no post value means `coursecode = None`

here i am finding like below:

```
if (coursecode != 'None') and (courselist == 'None' and semesteryear == 'None' and semesterseason == 'None'):
    course_listobj = Course.objects.filter(code=coursecode).order_by('code')
```

like above multiple if conditions are required.
pls suggest me any one how can i do one query with multiple conditions.

Edit (Working code for combination of if conditions):

```
    coursecode = request.POST['coursecode']
    courselist = request.POST['courselist']
    semesteryear = request.POST['semesteryear']
    semesterseason = request.POST['semesterseason']

    courses = Course.objects.all().order_by(
        'code', 'title', 'semester_year', 'semester_season')

    coursecodequery = Q(code=coursecode) if coursecode != 'None' else Q()
    courselistquery = Q(title=courselist) if courselist != 'None' else Q()
    semesteryearquery = Q(semester_year=semesteryear) if semesteryear != 'None' else Q()
    semesterseasonquery = Q(semester_season=semesterseason) if semesterseason != 'None' else Q()

    course_listobj = courses.filter(
        coursecodequery & courselistquery & semesteryearquery & semesterseasonquery
    )

    if coursecode == 'None' and courselist == 'None' and semesteryear == 'None' and semesterseason == 'None':
       messages.info(request, 'Please select all fields')

    if not course_listobj:
       messages.info(request, 'No matching courses')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `filter` conditions. For example:

```
courses = Course.objects.all().order_by(
  'code', 'title', 'semester_year', 'semester_season')
if coursecode != 'None':
    courses = courses.filter(code=coursecode)
if courselist != 'None':
    courses = courses.filter(title=courselist)
if semesteryear != 'None':
    courses = courses.filter(semester_year=semesteryear)
if semesterseason != 'None':
    courses = courses.filter(semester_season=semesterseason)
```

Note that your `order_by` clause can be fixed as those columns will always be returned in the result, regardless of they are in the `filter` or not.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but i tried same thing issue is if two request value is not empty other two values are empty means again i have to write if (coursecode !='None' and courselist !='None) and (semesteryear == 'None' and semesterseason == 'None'):

Comment: likewise 4c3 = 24 if conditons will come

Comment: is there any way to construct query under for loop to eliminate empty request value ( i mean concatenate filter query) like Course.objects.filter(code=coursecode).filter(title=courselist).filter(semester_year=semesteryear)

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. You don't have to write such a condition as all `if` are independent above. Empty ones (i.e. `"None"`) will be skipped. Just try it. You can also make this into a `for` loop but for 4 conditions this is much more readable.

Comment: @ Selcuk Combination of values are not working if i choose two drop down values query result giving one result only, it means if i choose drop down code and courselist only code related fields giving. How can i find code and courselist combination records in the database

Comment: Because you are using **elif** conditions , change to **if** like Selcuk answer

Comment: @Utkucan i changed can you look at my above code exact combination of and  statements giving result but it wont'be contain search result it gives only one matching if condition result ...

Comment: @somesh Chaining filters will match records that satisfy *all* of the conditions (i.e. they are combined with logical `and`s). If you want to retrieve records that satisfy *any* of the conditions, you should have a look at [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and combine them using `or`.

Comment: Finally i got the solution @ Selcuk, @Utkucan Thank you so much i updated my answer above